# iOS - corona: how to increase circle's touch area without affecting the collisions?

Tags: ios, coronasdk, physics

I have a Corona SDK made game in which you have to throw a ball, but the ball is hard to throw on a device because it is too small. How do I increase the area which is sensible to touch around the ball?

I tried creating another big circle with a small alpha on top of it and making the balls coordinates conform to the circles coordinates every frame, but, since I had to include the circle in physics, it would affect my collisions. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some transparency to the image. This of course makes the image bigger, so you have to change your display.newImageRect() to adjust.  Then when you add your physics shape, just have it be the size of the actual ball.